# In React, what are the advantages of setState() over render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Any react component I can imagine that uses state can be rewritten to use props. For example:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {name: 'World'};
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.state.name}</div>;
    }
});

var name = 'World';

var element = React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));

function toggle_name() {
    name = (name == 'World') ? 'Universe' : 'World';
    element.setState({name: name});
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncv7w22n/)

If this would be *inside* another Component, you would write it with props anyway. But the same is possible with the **outermost component**:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});

var name = 'World';

React.render(<Hello name={name} />, document.getElementById('container'));

function toggle_name()
{
    name = (name == 'World') ? 'Universe' : 'World';
    React.render(<Hello name={name} />, document.getElementById('container'));
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4x2jk5w/)

So when should I use state then?

My variable `name` certainly has the role of state, that's why I wonder what I'd gain from using React's state system.

Comment: It's similar, in that it compares state and props. However there may be a difference in that it's asking "where to store state".

Comment: Exactly. I realize that my variable `name` has the role of state, that's why I wonder what I gain from using React's state system.

Answer (score 2):

For parent-child communication, simply pass props.

Use **state** to store the data your current page needs in your controller-view.

Use **props** to pass data & event handlers down to your child components.

These lists should help guide you when working with data in your components.

**Props**

- immutable (let's react do fast reference checks)
- used to pass data down from your view-controller(your top level component)
- better performance, use this to pass data to child components

**State**

- Should be managed in your view-controller(your top level component)
- mutable
- worse performace
- don't access this to from child components, pass it down with props instead

> For communication between two components that don't have a
>   parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event
>   system. Subscribe to events in componentDidMount(), unsubscribe in
>   componentWillUnmount(), and call setState() when you receive an event.
>   Flux pattern is one of the possible ways to arrange this.
>    -  https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html
>
> **What Components Should Have State?**
>
> Most of your components should simply take some data from props and
>   render it. However, sometimes you need to respond to user input, a
>   server request or the passage of time. For this you use state.
>
> Try to keep as many of your components as possible **stateless**. By doing
>   this you'll isolate the state to its most logical place and minimize
>   redundancy, making it easier to reason about your application.
>
> A common pattern is to create several **stateless** components that just
>   render data, and have a stateful component above them in the hierarchy
>   that passes its state to its children via props. The stateful
>   component encapsulates all of the interaction logic, while the
>   stateless components take care of rendering data in a declarative way.
>      - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-components-should-have-state
>
> **What Should Go in State?**
>
> State should contain data that a component's event handlers may change
>   to trigger a UI update. In real apps this data tends to be very small
>   and JSON-serializable. When building a stateful component, think about
>   the minimal possible representation of its state, and only store those
>   properties in this.state. Inside of render() simply compute any other
>   information you need based on this state. You'll find that thinking
>   about and writing applications in this way tends to lead to the most
>   correct application, since adding redundant or computed values to
>   state means that you need to explicitly keep them in sync rather than
>   rely on React computing them for you. 
>     -  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-should-go-in-state

Comment: Why is the "most logical place" for state in the top-level component (the view-controller as you call it)? Could be a good pattern, I'm simply not aware of it.

Comment: Mutating state from a lot different components becomes difficult with many small components. Since react encourages building tiny ui modules for encapsulation, it is easiest to manage your state from one place. 

Also you will get better performance with props for several reasons, some of which I haven't explored enough to explain at this point. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

`state` is your source of truth. If your source of truth is external to a component accept `props`. If your component determines it's own truth and modifies it over time use `state`. If two components require the same truth, find a common parent and store it there.

---

It's possible to pull all your `state` up to the outermost component, leaving all child components to use `props` only. You can even, as you say, pull all `state` out of all components so all components accept only `props`.

What you are doing is **maximising state impact potential** whereas you want to **minimise** it. Minimising the impact state improves how easily you can reason about your rendering.

> For each piece of state in your application: (1) Identify every component that renders something based on that state. (2) Find a common owner component (a single component above all the components that need the state in the hierarchy).
>
> [Thinking In React (Identify where your state should live)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live)

Put state as close as you can to the components that are impacted by it:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {stateParentAndChildCaresAbout: "someVariable"};
  },
  render: function() {
    return <Child tellMeWhatToDo={this.state.stateParentAndChildCaresAbout} />
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {stateOnlyChildCaresAbout: "someVariable"};
  },
  render: function() {
    return <span>{this.state.stateOnlyChildCaresAbout} {this.props.tellMeWhatToDo}</span>;
  } 
});
```

Comment: You should have one parent at the top of your component stack. This is your controller-view. This is the only page that should touch the state object. Please see my answer for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: I'd shy away from that approach. The [docs imply](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live) my approach.

Comment: All of the quoted text in my comment is from the react docs w/source links to the quoted material. The example you linked is a simple example meant for new react developers. You might be interested in watching this video by cory house on building applications with react from pluralsight : http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/react-flux-building-applications

Comment: Presumably you're recommending only the top level (view-controller as you call it) has state. I don't see any evidence recommending this in your answer. Isn't it the case that you are **maximising state impact potential** as I term it? Could you provide an argument for specifically that approach?

Comment: How do I set the state of the child by the way?